# Use R's Table function to cross-tabulate data grouped by another variable

Tags: r, dplyr, crosstab

**Background**

Here's a dataframe `d`:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","b","b"),                  
                product_code = c("B78","X31","C12","C12"),
                multiple_products = c(1,1,0,0),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**The Problem & What I Want**

I'm trying to make a cross-tabulation-style frequency table of `multiple_products` using base `R`'s `table` function, but I want to do so by  `ID` and not by row. Here's what I'm looking for:

```
0 1 
1 1
```

In other words, a table that says "there's 1 `ID` where `multiple_products` equals 0, and 1 `ID` where it equals 1".

**What I've Tried**

Here's my attempt so far using `dplyr`:

```
dtable <- d %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  table(d$multiple_products) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This code runs on my real dataset without errors, but it gives me the same result that `table(d$multiple_products)` would, namely this:

```
0 1 
2 2
```

Which indicates "2 rows where `multiple_products` equals 0, and 2 rows where it equals 1".

In the toy example I'm giving you here, this code doesn't even run, giving me the following error:

```
Error: Can't combine `ID` <character> and `multiple_products` <double>.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to check `n_distinct` by group

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
    group_by(multiple_products) %>% 
    summarise(n = n_distinct(ID))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  multiple_products     n
              <dbl> <int>
1                 0     1
2                 1     1
```